# Creating master list and details view in iOS

Tags: ios, oop

I have a scenario where in we have to show product list in one screen and show full detail screen on tapping on particular product. In the list we are showing only basic data related to product(title, thumbnail etc) But on the detail screen we show all the data related to the Product. So which is the best to way create model classes for this scenario? One option is to create a single class called **Product** and use it in both list and detail screen. Another option is to create a base class **BaseProduct** containing few properties required for the list screen and another class called **FullProduct** which inherits **BaseProduct** which will have the additional properties required in detail screen.

Comment: each of the views you describe show product information, so pass the product model in. It doesn't matter if they both display them differently, thats why you have *different* views in the first place

Comment: Thanks. Also in the list screen the product model doesn't contain all the details of the product. It will have only required values populated from backend to save internet usage and data download time. Only the detail view have all the data from details backend api. In this if we use same model for both the screen the list view should know that it can access only certain values. Is there a better way to document it? Also the Product model will have other unused values with default values set. Will this affect the memory usage when there is a huge number of products in the list?

Comment: There are alot of options available. you can either have a model that maps each response, or have generic model with optional values. it shouldn't make much difference having optional values that aren't used. the memory is probably reserved. You probably shouldn't be loading huge datasets anyway if you are concerned over memory